# Image display in JTable cell

Tags: java, swing, icons, jtable, imageicon

I use the following program for creating JTable using java class. If I get the images for warnIcon,infoIcon from optionpane it displays properly. However, if I add image from my system it doesn't display in table. A blank space is displayed instead of my image. How can I draw an image from file (e.g. A.jpg) in that table?

```
package pointer;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.plaf.OptionPaneUI;
import javax.swing.table.*;
import sun.swing.ImageIconUIResource;

public class TableIcon1 extends JFrame  {
    private JTable table;
    private int pHeight = 60;
       public TableIcon1() {
           ImageIcon testIcon = new ImageIcon("A.jpg");
          // ImageIcon errorIcon = (ImageIcon) UIManager.getIcon("OptionPane.errorIcon");
           ImageIcon infoIcon = (ImageIcon) UIManager.getIcon("OptionPane.informationIcon");
           ImageIcon warnIcon = (ImageIcon) UIManager.getIcon("OptionPane.warningIcon");
           String[] columnNames = {"Picture", "Description"};
           Object[][] data = {{testIcon  , "About"}, {infoIcon, "Add"}, {warnIcon, "Copy"},};
           DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);
           table = new JTable(model) {
            @Override
            public Class getColumnClass(int column) {
                return getValueAt(2, column).getClass();
            }
          };
           table.setRowHeight(pHeight);
           table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(table.getPreferredSize());
           JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
           add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
         }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TableIcon1 frame = new TableIcon1();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocation(150, 150);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: ***Why*** are you showing a `File` from the local file system?  If it is an application resource, it should be (put in a Jar, added to the run-time class-path &) obtained by URL.  If it is a 'user resource', offer the user a `JFileChooser` and you'll get back a `File` object with a full path and name.  Either way would solve this problem.  Other points: 1) Don't extend `JFrame`.  Prefer composition over inheritance. 2) Construct the GUI on the EDT.  3) `setLocationByPlatform(true)` is better than `setLocation(150, 150)`.

Comment: @AndrewThompson how to add JFilechooser for testicon in this example

Comment: Why don't you give it your best attempt after reading [How to Use File Choosers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html)?  If you get stuck, ask a specific question.  BTW - don't presume I can read your mind.  Does your question mean the image is ***not*** an application resource as mKorbel is presuming?  (More information is better than less, generally.)

Comment: @javalearner : Where is your image folder located ?

Comment: URL url = getClass().getResource("image/Pointer.GIF");
           ImageIcon testIcon = new ImageIcon(url); it was work properly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ImageIcon testIcon = new ImageIcon("A.jpg"); is road to nowhere
```

Icon is common that never returns any exceptions for wrong path or null value, you have to test fro that

best of way would be create a new folder with name `icons` in your `Java project` and there copy your `A.jpg Icon`

then you can only call

```
URL url = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResource("icons/A.jpg");
ImageIcon testIcon = new ImageIcon(url);
```

Comment: -1 I _knew_ that crappy systemClassLoader would bubble up again - with a good probability that it would be _you_ ;-)

Comment: URL url = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResource("icons/A.jpg");
ImageIcon testIcon = new ImageIcon(url); I have the null pointer exception .how to solve this?

Comment: @mKorbel : Yeah, a wonderful document once shown to me by "kleopatra", too true try this link, why we must use getClass().getResource() and not ClassLoaders thingy [Application Resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/lang/resources.html)  +1 :-)  Regards

Comment: @Gagandeep Bali thanks, but nobody convinced me about converse, simple accepted,

Comment: @mKorbel : Here check this line in that "All class loaders will search for a resource first as a system resource, in a manner analogous to searcing for class files."

Comment: URL url = getClass().getResource("image/Pointer.GIF");
  ImageIcon testIcon = new ImageIcon(url); I use like this it will display the image